# Xamarin android hangs on start

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using visual studio 15.7.4

Xamarin 4.10.10.2

Xamarin forms project

compile version api level 26

target android version api level 26

release mode

sdk link assemblies only

using Xamarin forms 3.1.0

Issue:
app starts fine (although long startup time) in debug mode.  After installed to 2 different real phones the app splash screen shows on launch but hangs indefinitely

Comment: check for deadlocks.from mixing async/await with blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()`

Comment: I had a .Result in there, let me get rid of that and try deploying again.  Thanks

Comment: @Nkosi although that code isn't executed until the user presses a button so I'm not sure if that matters?

Comment: then check the code that runs initially and look for bottlenecks that could be causing the slow down.

Comment: That's the thing.  I can't find any.  App used to work fine

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to enable "Zipalign" on the "Signing and aligning APK file(s)" task in my Xamarin Android build definition on Azure Devops (previously VSTS). I got the answer from [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97113/xamarin-android-app-crash-to-start-in-device)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be something with the build definition in VSTS, as it worked when built right from Visual Studio

Comment: I have the exact same problem, how did you fix your build definition?

Comment: I actually couldn't spend any more time grinding this out so I'm just building in Visual Studio and releasing through App Center